# Extending a non abstract class and implementing an interface with same method signatures in a class

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I have the following classes and interface

```
public class A {
  public void printSomething() {
    System.out.println("printing from A");
  }
}

interface B {
  public void printSomething();
}

public class C extends A implements B {
  public static void main(String aa[]) {
    C c = new C();
    c.printSomething();
  }
}
```

When I compile the above code, it compiles without any errors. And when I run the program it prints the following.

```
printing from A
```

I was expecting the compiler to give a similar error like the following error that I got when my class C **did not extend** class A

```
 C.java:1: error: C is not abstract and does not override abstract method printSomething() in B public class C implements B{
       ^
C.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                        c.printSomething();
                         ^
  symbol:   method printSomething()
  location: variable c of type C
2 errors
```

I know that when a class implements an interface then we need to define the interface methods in the class or declare the class abstract. But then how just by extending a class (with a defined method of same signature) am I able to overcome this compiler warning and run the program as well.

Comment: It's because you are inheriting this method from the super class. The method has to be provided, and, through inheritance, it is

Comment: Why were you expecting this? Inheritance means that a `C` can be treated as an `A`; and `A` has that method...

Comment: implementing the `interface` forces you to have acces to the method defined in the `interface` in the class, not to actually have it written inside the class that does implement the `interface`. If the class does inherit from a class that did already define the method and it has access to it the conditions are fullfilled and hence you don´t need to overwrite the method again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely fine to do that and is surprisingly common.

You are using `class A` as a tool for *implementing* the `interface` specified by `interface B`.

This sort of pattern facilitates modularisation and the potential for code reuse.

Comment: So you mean if I want a default implementation to a function then I can achieve that using the above pattern? And override the function in any of the sub classes where required

Comment: Absolutely. `class C` can provide it's own implementation of `printSomething` if you want it to do something different.

Comment: Thanks!! That helped

Answer (score 0):

This is because C is child of A. Whenever Child default contractor gets executed, its parent constructor gets called ( this is to inherit all the property of A ).
In this case, "new C()" made all the property of A() available to class C including printSomething().

Comment: what has calling the superclass's constructor got to do with this? You don't call that constructor to "inherit all the property", it is called to make sure that the super class's members are instantiated

Comment: the super class members are instantiated which means a block of memory is allocated to the resources which are accessible by the child elements whenever needed ( except private resources ). This is nothing but indirectly opening all the resources to its children.

Comment: it's the "extends" keyword that gives access to the (non-private) super-members.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, by extending `class A` into `class C`, you actually providing implementation to the `printSomething()` method of `interface B`.

**Please Note:**,`class A` consist an implementation of `printSomething()` method.